# undefined (reading 'videos')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Trying to get a discord bot to join a channel and play a link but I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videos')
```

my command handler is fine with other simpler commands

```
    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    }
```

This is the line that gets me the error

Comment: Please add a check for `videoResult` first like `videoResult && (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;`

Comment: The error means that `videoResult` contains the value `undefined` and thus `await ytSearch(query)` is returning `undefined`. We don't know what `ytSearch` is doing, so we can't really help you any further without a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks it got past that point!

Comment: @SneakyPorcini Sure, it'll go past that point. But there is no way of knowing whether it will work as intended without seeing `ytSearch`. Your `videoFinder` function might very well _always_ return `null` (or another falsy value) now.

Comment: @Ivar yeah it doesn't play the song it always returns null. this is my play.js https://pastebin.com/bPzauCRn

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this :

```js
const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult?.videos?.length > 1) ? videoResult?.videos[0] : null;
    }
```

The `?` will check the object before exists. If not, it returns `undefined` and in your case, null, because `undefined.videos` doesn't exist.

Alternatively :

```js
const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
        if (!videoResult || !videoResult.videos) return null
        return videoResult.videos[0]
    }
```

Comment: Tried it and it goes past that point but it outputs a typeerror in the console
TypeError: t is not a function
in the file node_modules\yt-search\dist\yt-search.min.js:1:1087

Comment: Then you might have an other error, but it's not caused by the snippet.

Comment: fixed it by installing the latest yt-search rookie mistake